# Sylow tower in a supersoluble finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let a finite supersoluble group $G$ and let $p$ a prime number.

Let $\pi=\{q$ is prime number$: q\ge p\}$.
Then i want proof that $G$ has a normal Sylow $\pi$-subgroup (i.e. normal Hall $\pi$-subgroup):

Let $P$ a Sylow $\pi$-group of $G$. It's sufficient proof that $P\triangleleft G$.

I want to proceed by induction on $|G|$. The base of induction $G=\{1\}$ is obvious.

For $|G|\ge 2$, i considered $N$ normal minimal subgroup of $G$. $G$ supersoluble implies that $|N|=q$ prime number.

I  apply induction hypotesis on $\displaystyle\frac{G}{N}$ and therefore $\displaystyle\frac{PN}{N}\triangleleft \displaystyle\frac{G}{N}$. Then $PN\triangleleft G$.

I am now stuck and i ask for help. How use the particolar structure of $\pi$?
I have to distinguish if $q\in \pi$ or $q\notin \pi$?

Answer (score 1):

If $q \in \pi$, then $PN$ is a $\pi$-group, so $PN=P$ and you are done.

Otherwise ($q \not\in \pi$), we have  $q < p$ for all primes $p$ dividing $|P|$ and, since $|{\rm Aut }(N)| = p-1$ is not divisible by any prime dividing $|P|$, we have $PN = P \times N$, so $P$ is characteristic in $PN$, and hence $P \lhd G$.